# How do I restrict permission to change the primaryGroupID attribute in Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, acl

I am changing the `primaryGroupID` attribute in `Active Directory` on the user.
I do it through PowerShell. I'm doing great!

```
Set-ADUser -Server domain.local -Identity KUL -Replace @{PrimaryGroupID=123456}
```

I want to run `PowerShell` from the service account `service1`.
How do I assign `service1` only the right to change the `primaryGroupID` [attribute?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-primarygroupid)

I run Control Panel -> All Control Panel Items -> Administrative Tools -> `Active Directory Users and Computers`

Select Root My Domain -> Security -> Advanced -> Add -> `Select a Principal (service 1); Allow; Descendant User object`

But I don't see the `primaryGroupID` (relative identifier (RID)) attribute!

How do I add a security rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer! Through the GUI, this can only be done through ADSI!

[For instance, if you wish to delegate this permission to a particular user or group for user objects in a particular OU, you need to open adsiedit, connect to the default naming context, navigate to the OU in question, right click and open Properties, select Security then Advanced.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/2e87c55c-e596-4cf2-a1e1-828540d520ad/delegate-permission-to-set-primary-group?forum=winserverDS)

I also wrote a module in PowerShell to **change** the **PrimaryGroupID** of a user in **Active Directory**. Maybe someone will come in handy - [ADPGID](https://github.com/isKUL/NSPA/tree/main/ADPGID)